# Restricting iOS Version to < iOS 9 with HockeyApp

Tags: ios, versioning, hockeyapp

I have an app with a library that is unsupported on iOS 9, I'd like to avoid the user experience of the app crashing for our testers (which is what happens when running the build on iOS 9).

While I'm waiting for the vendor to update their library is there a way to restrict downloads of the app from Hockey App (I haven't found a way in our settings).

The only alternative I can think of is trying to get the app to not crash long enough to check the version and raise a notification but that does nothing for our existing builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The best you can do is, if possible, put an availability check and only use the framework if you are running < 9.0.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  We'll just have to add the check and be a bit more forceful in educating the external testers.

Comment: Also, I might add that if you are looking for alternatives to HockeyApp, I suggest you look into either Twitter's "Fabric" or Apple's "TestFlight". They are both very easy to integrate (I might also add that Apple's version gives you version compatibility for free).

Comment: Thanks for the steer toward Fabric.  Will look into it.  I've been a test flight user since beta, but we're cross platform so no good for use now that is it in Apple's capable hands. :)

Comment: If there is anything wrong or missing in HockeyApp, feel free to contact us via support :)